# What if only parent version in POM?

Tags: java, maven, dependency-management, pom.xml

Inspecting various POMs I saw that sometimes they have `<version>` tags only in `<parent>` section. Sometimes they have the following code `<version>${parent.version}</version>` in the main section along with version in parent.

Which version value will be used in these various cases?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The version from the parent, in both cases.

[See the "Introduction to the POM" for implicit version inheritance info.](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-pom.html#The_Solution)

[See this document for further information regarding what else is inherited.](http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Inheritance)

Answer (score 1):

It will "inherit" the version from the parent and it does many other pieces of configuration.  The `groupId` and `dependencies` can come from the parent as well.